# Getting error while executing command as "minikube start"

Tags: kubernetes

I'm Getting error while executing the command `minikube start`

**System details:**
DELL, OS: Windows 7 with Virtulazation Enabled.

Please help me find an appropriate solution for this.

**The error-message:**

> C:\Users\admin>minikube.exe start Starting local Kubernetes v1.10.0
>   cluster... Starting VM... Downloading Minikube ISO
>    150.53 MB / 150.53 MB [============================================] 100.00% 0s Getting VM IP address... Moving files into cluster... Downloading kubeadm v1.10.0 Downloading kubelet v1.10.0 Finished
>   Downloading kubelet v1.10.0 Finished Downloading kubeadm v1.10.0
>   Setting up certs... Connecting to cluster... Setting up kubeconfig...
>   Starting cluster components... E0524 03:59:38.568748    5880
>   start.go:276] Error starting cluster:  kubeadm init error sudo
>   /usr/bin/kubeadm init --config /var/l ib/kubeadm.yaml
>   --ignore-preflight-errors=DirAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests --ignore-preflight-errors=DirAvailable--data --ig nore-preflight-errors=FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-kube-scheduler.yaml
>   --ignore-preflight-errors=FileAvailable--etc-kub ernetes-manifests-kube-apiserver.yaml
>   --ignore-preflight-errors=FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-kube-controller-manager.ya
>   ml
>   --ignore-preflight-errors=FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-etcd.yaml
>   --ignore-preflight-errors=Swap --ignore-preflight-e rrors=CRI  running command: : running command: sudo /usr/bin/kubeadm init --config
>   /var/lib/kubeadm.yaml --ignore-preflight-errors
>   =DirAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests --ignore-preflight-errors=DirAvailable--data --ignore-preflight-errors=FileAvailable--etc- kubernetes-manifests-kube-scheduler.yaml
>   --ignore-preflight-errors=FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-kube-apiserver.yaml
>   --i gnore-preflight-errors=FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-kube-controller-manager.yaml
>   --ignore-preflight-errors=FileAvailabl e--etc-kubernetes-manifests-etcd.yaml --ignore-preflight-errors=Swap
>   --ignore-preflight-errors=CRI  output: [init] Using Kubernetes version: v1.10.0 [init] Using Authorization modes: [Node RBAC]
>   [preflight] Running pre-flight checks.
>
> [WARNING Swap]: running with swap on is not supported. Please disable swap Flag --admission-control has been deprecated, Use
>   --enable-admission-plugins or --disable-admission-plugins instead. Will be remov ed in a future version. failure loading ca certificate:
>   the certificate is not valid yet : running command: sudo
>   /usr/bin/kubeadm init --config /var/lib/kubeadm.yaml
>   --ignore-preflight-errors=DirAvailable--etc-kubernete s-manifests --ignore-preflight-errors=DirAvailable--data --ignore-preflight-errors=FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-kube-sc
>   heduler.yaml
>   --ignore-preflight-errors=FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-kube-apiserver.yaml
>   --ignore-preflight-errors=FileA vailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-kube-controller-manager.yaml
>   --ignore-preflight-errors=FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests- etcd.yaml --ignore-preflight-errors=Swap --ignore-preflight-errors=CRI
>   .: Process exited with status 1

Answer (score 0):

> failure loading ca certificate: the certificate is not valid yet

Check the date, time and timezone on your laptop, looks like it is incorrect and it is the reason of the problem.

Comment: I have verified the Date, Time and Timezone. It's looking correct.

Comment: Try to run `minikube` with `--v=3` or `--v=7` flag, publish the output somewhere and post here a link. That is a debug mode, now the only error I see in your log is about a certificate.